# Apk file from vserv AppWrapper cannot be installed

Tags: android

I have an .apk file that already working (final). After I am using appwrapper from vserv.mobi, it says that the wrapping process is completed. But when I am installing that apps in my android phone (android 2.3.4), it says "Application not installed". Is there anyone have the solution? Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have signed your App. You can either use the AppWrapper itself to sign your app or use [jarsigner](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode) .

PS: If you try installing the App using [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#move) it should throw an error letting you know why the App did not install

Comment: I have try both not signing the app and signing the app using Vserv AppWrapper itself.

Comment: We could take the discussion offline, please e-mail me ravi @ vserv.mobi

Answer (score -1):

I've got the solution decompile your apk with winrar copy the meta inf folder back from the old apk to the new apk and woala compile it again sign it with zip signer /jar signer ... and it's done . Install it (meta inf ,won't be copied if appwrapper wraps a app)